# ASP Page has data truncated

Tags: html, asp-classic

ASP page is not being displayed completely.  When viewing, user cannot scroll to end of page, data is truncated.  When viewing the web page source, all of the data is present.  When I save the web page source as a html file, then load in browser, all data is scrollable.

note:  user can scroll to see most of the data, but not all.  Cannot scroll to end of web page.

Comment: This most likely is a problem with the style of the page, not with `ASP`. Can you provide a link/more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this bhavio when the ASP page is being sloppy about the HTML it's producing.  For example, I saw this in a page that forgot to put the

```
"</tr>"
```

tag at the end of each table row.  So it looked like

```
<table>
<tr>
 <td>stuff</td>
 <td>more stuff</td>
<tr>
 <td>stuff</td>
 <td>more stuff</td>
```

Essentially, browsers allow some sloppiness in the html, so the browsers were able to compensate and display the page "correctly for the first hundred rows or so, but eventually, it got to the point where the browser just stopped processing the page.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that there is an error in your HTML, if a div is not closed properly I have seen this occur. Also see what it looks like in Firefox, as firefox will try to correct the HTML error.

The other possibility is that the CSS has a problem. Try removing your style sheet to see if you can see all the data.

Comment: problem also occurs in Firefox

Comment: Removed CSS, problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Found my solution.  My iframe was being set to a fixed height.  Added javascript code to adjust iframe height based on content.  Found solution here:  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/Adjust_An_iFrame_Height.aspx